# Move ownership of a member from one struct to another?

Tags: rust

I have 2 structs:

```
struct MyVector {
    storage: Vec<u32>,
}

struct MyVectorBuilder {
    storage: Vec<u32>,
}

impl MyVectorBuilder {
    fn new() -> MyVectorBuilder {
        MyVectorBuilder { storage: Vec::new() }
    }

    fn build_my_vector(&mut self) -> MyVector {
        // Doesn't compile: ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
        MyVector { storage: self.storage }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to tell the compiler that `MyVectorBuilder` will not be used following a call to `build_my_vector()` so it will let me move the `storage` to `MyVector`?

Comment: Note: you may want to get better acquainted with Rust naming conventions, methods should be `snake_case` not `PascalCase`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Thanks, old habits

Comment: No worries, the compiler will remind you over and over until you comply :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Pass ownership of `MyVectorBuilder` into `MakeMyVector`

```
fn make_my_vector(self) -> MyVector {
    MyVector { storage: self.storage }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to tell the compiler that `MyVectorBuilder` will not be used followning a call to `BuildMyVector()` so it will let me move the storage to `MyVector` ?

Yes, taking `MyVectorBuilder` by value:

```
fn build_my_vector(self) -> MyVector {
    MyVector { storage: self.storage }
}
```

In general, I recommend that the `build` step of a builder takes its argument by value for precisely this reason.

If building twice is necessary, the builder can implement `Clone`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in Rust 1.40.0, you can use the [mem::take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html) function.

```
fn build_my_vector(&mut self) -> MyVector {
    MyVector { storage: take(self.storage) }
}
```